# How to save the current file using gstreamer?

Tags: c, media, gstreamer

```
    _loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    _pipeline = gst_element_factory_make("playbin", "player");

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(_pipeline), "uri", "localhost/exampleFile.mp3", NULL);

    _bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(_pipeline));
    gst_bus_add_watch(_bus, busCall, NULL);
    gst_object_unref(_bus);

    gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(_pipeline), GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    g_main_loop_run(_loop);

    gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(_pipeline), GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(_pipeline));
```

I can play any file by this code, but I need save currently playing file to my hard drive.
I could not find an example that would allow me to do it. There is a variant with audio-sink and video-sink, but I do not know how to unite them. It would be nice to see a working example that would allow it to be implemented.

Comment: Please add in the OP if you want to save mp3(audio only) or video too if file played is container.

Comment: I want to keep be able to save any audio/video

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [filesink](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-filesink.html) element.

```
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(_your_filesink_element), "location", "/home/yourlocation/file3.mp3", NULL);
```

This means directly linking it with source four saving it properly through a separate `pipeline`  or maybe using `queue`.

Comment: I try to use it but i dont know how to connect filesink to pipeline. Do you have a simple example ?